# Get text inside <p> tag to a <table>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In PHP this is the output I managed to get from a calculation

```
<p id="generated">12345678199824,12345678411140,12345678921494,12345678497535,</p>
```

and I need this values to be as below

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>12345678199824</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>12345678411140</td>
 </tr>
.....
</table>
```

Below is the js script I used

```
$("#setVal").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var noOfImei = parseInt($("#nofoemei").val());
    var imeiList = "";
    if (noOfImei !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < noOfImei; i++) {
            imeiList += $("#binnumber").val() + Math.floor(Math.random()*900000+100000) + ",";
        }

        $("#generated").text("");
        $("#generated").text(imeiList);

        // testing purpose
        console.log(imeiList);
    } else {
        alert("Please add no of IMEI(s) need to generate");
    }
});
```

--
Please not Im a beginner to PHP and JS and managed to progress this far with help of stackoverflow and tutorials.
Thank You.

Comment: dont use a string, use an array, then loop over it and append to a table `$('table').append('<tr><td>' + item + '</td></tr>')`.

Comment: How does your generated PHP reach the front end? are you using ajax? or is all of this happening in a single file?

Comment: @MHewison its happening in a single file

Comment: you could store the imei list as a php array and use json_encode() then use that value to loop without dealing with the p tags, which you could also create in js

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#generated").text("");
  $("#generated").text(imeiList);
  data = imeiList.split(",")
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  for(let i =0;i<data.length ; i++){
   var row = table.insertRow(i); 
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = data[i];
  }
```

And

```
<table id="myTable" /> // this in dom
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the related string and via split create an array. then add rows like follwing:

```js
document.getElementById("setVal").addEventListener("click", function(){
let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
let nums = document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML;
  if(nums){
    nums.split(',').forEach(i=> {
      let row = table.insertRow(0);
      let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      cell1.innerHTML = i;
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="generated">
12345678199824,12345678411140,12345678921494,12345678497535,</p> 

<input type="button" id="setVal" value="Set Rows"/>

<table id="myTable" style="border: 1px solid red;">
 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of PHP initially you must explode your string and then by counting the string length it becomes more simpler to add a `for` loop

```
<?php
$str = "12345678199824,12345678411140,12345678921494,12345678497535";
$str1 =  explode(",",$str);
$arrlength=count($str1);
?> 
<table style = "border:1px solid;border-collapse : collapse;">
<?php
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  ?>
 <tr style = "border:1px solid;">
 <td style = "border:1px solid;"><?php echo $str1[$x]?></td>
 <tr>

  <?php } ?>
  </table>
```

**Note :** Select the correct separator(in this example it is '**,**') in the `explode()` function.